# How to create table (set returning) function in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I tried to create a table (set returning) function in redshift but failed.

Because redshift only supports scalar function ([documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html)). Is it true? Can I create table functions?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, as per the docs redshift supports scalar only.  if you share your requirement and what you have tried so far we may be able to help you find another way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for you answer. It helped for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer: no you can not create table functions ("set returning functions) as you can do in Postgres.

The section [Unsupported PostgreSQL Features](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html)  in the Redshift manual explicitly lists "Table functions".